# How to add a grid to UserControl programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, customtaskpane

I have a WPF User Control which contains nothing in it, and I'm passing a grid control to it, how do I add that grid control to the empty User Control?

Comment: `userControl.Content = grid;` probably

Comment: yeah it worked but the missing the user control resources of the passed grid in the received User control.

Comment: Consider make your answer into an answer so it can be accepted as the answer.

Comment: @govardhan, include all relevant information in the question. it didn't say anything about resources

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code on how to achieve to add a grid programmatically. This grid contains 3 equal rows and 3 equal columns. Change it to something you want to have.

```
Grid grid1 = new Grid{Width = 300, Height = 400};
grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
UserControl1.Content = grid1;
```